# How can I manage the symptom of forgetfulness in a patient with dementia?

Tags: mental-health, dementia, brain-exercises, short-term-memory-loss, forgetfulness

I am a caregiver of a dementia patient, who forgets things all the time. I would like to know how to manage this symptom of dementia so I can help the patient. What should I do about this forgetfulness?

Is it advisable to use memory aids?

Comment: Hi! I re-worded your question because it felt a little bit hard to see exactly what you needed. If what I did was wrong, I apologize. If the edit gets accepted, feel free to return the question to how you had it. It's great how important your patient is to you, and I hope you get some help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pictures of the patients family with captions saying who they are and their relationship to the individual.

If they are still able (but forgetful) in the kitchen put pictures on the cupboard fronts to show what is in them. If they can't get the right order of a task e.g puts water in the teacup and then switches on the kettle. Try putting together a storyboard of the task;
1 Put water in the kettle
2 Switch the kettle on.
3 Take Mug from cupboard
and so on.

If you are in the UK the Alzheimer's Society has information and Resources to help. No doubt similar information exists in other countries.

A friend of my father-in-law would forget to take her medication - so a dosage box was obtained that could be programmed to open the section for today at the appropriate time the tablet should be taken. Of course they can still forget what the opening of the dosage box means for them, if no one is with them.

If they are forgetting their husband or wife they can get distressed by that partner getting frustrated by the fact they are not remembering who the patient is married to. As hard as it is, just keep calm and cool and keep saying each time I'm Fred\Bill\Mary (insert name here) your husband\wife.

Comment: Here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283).